# jQuery: making a div inside ajaxcall

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok. If you didnt spell a full name right, and only entered the lastname, and the there exist more users with that lastname, in the recipient field, the ajax call will return an error with

Who did you mean:
 Mami Fox 
 Megan Fox 
 Blabla Fox

Now, I would like to make so you can click on them, choose who you meant to send to.

To do this I cannot use confirm, as confirm only have OK/CANCEL.

So i got told to use jQuery BlockUI Plugin, or just making a div and show().

But how can I prepend the error in a div(i know this), show it(i know this), and then make so you are able to click on them, and receive a alert on click ('you have chosen Mami Fox').

As i cannot make an prepared div with the names in(as the name are suggested from the page ajax requested, sendPM.php), and so, I would like to know how to do this.

--

Firstly i guess i would need to make json variable for each name. e.g

```
 name1 : 'Mami Fox', name2 : 'Megan Fox', name3: 'Blabla Fox'
```

So in the div you can then prepend the names in there(instead of one variable with all names including "Who did you mean"), and make them so when you click on them, it will say "You have chosen"+data.name1 (example, where data is callback function name from the ajax success)..

--Just a thought.

Comment: how do you get that names? into an array? I guess something like: {names:['Mami Fox','Megan Fox','Blabla Fox']}

Comment: @Dalen ... you should probably look up javascript arrays and JSON elements

Comment: @drachenstern yep, you are right this should be correct {"names": ["Mami Fox","Megan Fox","Blabla Fox" ]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to create a workflow that supports the process that you want. This means using a flowchart or something. You can't just code the solution, you have to design it.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow

So the user selects a last name, but more than one last name exists.

BRANCH WORKFLOW FROM "STANDARD"

Build a list of all possible choices.

Present the user with a dialog to choose the appropriate name from the given list.

User selects a name.

RESUME WORKFLOW TO "STANDARD"

Comment: ..yes? that is how i want? Yes i can make a flowchart, I already know how it shall work. But that's not what i need help with its the coding of it. I have builded a list of choices. And present. I get stuck at "user selects a name", how can i make so user can select/pick a name, and then alert out the name he picked.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the AJAX call, it only has to be an onclick attached to the inserted elements.

Comment: No, because the Ajax call return an JSON with "names", and these names should be the elements.

Comment: $("#pmResponse").html("<a class='SuggestionName' id='name'>name</a>").show(); This is what I have now. How can i make a loop that makes a link for each name from the JSON "names" ?

Comment: Ok that worked fine. How can I make a JSON variable that contains more names?